# Meaning of the adjective "clear" in the context of "blips of energy"

Tags: meaning-in-context

It was in [Crash Course Big History](https://youtu.be/L-T2SSsMREM?t=3m3s). It is at 3 minute and 16 second. Here is the context:

> When the universe was still very, very small at the quantum scale, tiny fluctuations were popping in and out of existence. These tiny blips of energy usually don't affect the physics of the larger world. But, during inflation, they suddenly were **clear**, when the universe became big, causing slight inequalities in matter and energy.

I cannot get how tiny blips can become clear, and what it means there. Could you please rephrase the  sentence for me?

Comment: The word **clear** can mean something like "free to progress, no obstacles in the way".   We can say "We're clear to go" when what we mean is "There's nothing preventing or blocking us from going".  It is roughly synonymous with **free**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the context, I think the speaker meant to say "they suddenly *became* clear".  That is to say, that which did not previously affect the physics of the larger world suddenly resolved more fully into existence.